# Don't scratch. The more you scratch the more itchy

Tags: word-choice

He was bitten by mosquito.

He scratched the spots.

> "Don't scratch. The more you scratch the more itchy."
>
> "Don't scratch. The more you scratch the more itches"

What word best suit in the sentences above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these sentences is grammatically correct.  In the first one, the word *itchy* is an adjective which needs a noun to decribe.  eg:

> Don't scratch. The more you scratch the more itchy **it becomes**.

In the second, the word *itches* is a verb which needs a subject. eg.:

> Don't scratch. The more you scratch the more **it** itches.

The choice between these two is a matter of style. I prefer the second because of the repitition of structure: you scratch -- it itches.

Comment: Can I say, "Don't scratch. It will getting itches."?

Comment: @e12345678, no, that is not grammatical. We can *scratch an itch*, but we don't normally talk about *itches* in the plural. We'd more likely say we have several *itchy spots*.